# Помогите перевести htaccess в nginx

Tags: .htaccess, apache, nginx

всем привет ребят помогите перевести, уже 3 часа бьюсь.

```
#======================================
# Устанавливаем кодировку
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#======================================
# Назначаем файл индекса
DirectoryIndex index.php

#======================================
# Защита от листинга файлов
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

#======================================
# Инициализация модуля реврайт
RewriteEngine On

#======================================
# Защита от Кроссскриптинга
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule .* - [F]

#======================================
# При запросе файла .htaccess говорим, что он не существует.
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ -[F]

#======================================
# При запросе системныйх папок говорим, что их не существует.
RewriteRule ^(template|plugins|inc)$ - [R=404]

#======================================
# Убераем имя индексного файла из адреса
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index[.]+(\w+)$
RewriteRule . /embed/ [R=301,L]

#======================================
# Перенаправляем все запросы на index.php если этоне файл, папка или ссылка
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(/embed/)\?(.*)$ $1?$2 [L]
```

Вот что навоял.

```
    location /embed/ {
        if ($request_method ~ "^TRACE") {
            return 403;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
        location ~* (template|plugins|inc) {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~* /template/.+\.tpl {
            deny all;
        }
        if ($request_uri ~ "/index.(php|html|htm?)") {
            rewrite ^ /embed/$1 permanent;
        }
        #if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/(/embed/)\?(.*)$ /$1?$2 last;
        #}
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А где ваш конфиг nginx, который вы 3 часа наваяли?

Comment: Добавил посмотрите